# Is $u,v,w$ a basis of $\text{span}(u,v,w)$, and why?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $u = (1, 2, 0, 1)$, $v = (1, −1, 1, 0)$, $w = (2, 4, 0, 2)$, and suppose $W = \text{span}(u, v, w)$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$.
Is $u,v,w$ a basis of $W$? Why or why not?

I'm not sure if it is or not, I reduced it down to echelon form.
$$ \left[
    \begin{array}{cccc}
      1&2&0&1\\
      0&1&-1/3&1/3\\
      0&0&0&0
    \end{array}
\right] $$

But I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: The bottom row consists of all zeros.  What does that tell you about whether $u, v, w$ are linearly independent?  What would have to be true for $u, v, w$ to be linearly independent.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Recall that a set $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis for $W$ if $Span\mathcal{B}=W$ and $\mathcal{B}$ is linearly independent. In your problem, $\{u,v,w\}$ spans $W$ by definition of $W$. So you only have to check the linear (in)dependence of $\{u,v,w\}$. How can you relate linear independence of rows of a matrix to the number of rows that have all zero entries in the matrix's reduced echelon form?

Comment: Since SpanB is not linear independent because of the zero row than it is not a basis for W right?

Comment: You got it, Blare!

Comment: @Blare: you have the right idea! *But* be careful with your terms.  $\mathcal B$ is a set of vectors, while $\operatorname{Span} \mathcal B$ is a vector space.  A vector space can't be linearly (in)dependent.  What you mean is that $\mathcal B$ is linearly dependent.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Question does it matter that W is a subspace of R4 and what if all three vectors were linear independent would they form a basis even though there are only 3 vectors? Thank you very much!

Comment: @Blare: The dimension of the “ambient” space ($\mathbb{R}^4$ in this case) doesn't matter, except that three vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$ can't be linearly independent.  The answer to your second question is yes: A basis of a vector (sub)space is a linearly independent spanning set.  $W$ is, by construction, spanned by $u$, $v$, and $w$, so if those three are linearly independent, they form a basis for $W$.

Answer (score 4):

Hint:

The three vectors are a basis iff they are linearly independent, but
 a simple inspection shows that $w=2u$ (as confirmed by your echelon form reduction), so ......

Comment: I only edited (added one letter) to change "tree" to "three" vectors...

Comment: Well, your mastery of English is exceptional!  I've got a sticky "e" key on my keyboard, which requires a forceful finger to render.  So I've been guilty of typing "th"  instead of "the" etc.  No need to worry about your English!...Typos happen!!

Answer (score 2):

If $u, v, w $  are linearly independent and span $ W $, then they form a basis.

But you can see that they are not linearly independent. As your echelon form suggests,  $w$ could be turned into a zero vector by the linear combination of $u$ and $v$.

For the definition of linear independence, check this wiki [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_independence).

More precisely,

$w$ = 2$u$

This means that $w$ is redundant and you only need two vectors i.e. $u$ and $v$     to describe every vector in the subspace $W$.